# How can I change the text color in IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a html page with an IFrame linking towards a text file, my html page's body is set to black, and the default color of the IFrame txt is black, so I cannot see my text :/
I would like to know how to change the text color, thanks. zeokila

```
<iframe src="http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt" width="470" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="overflow-x:hidden"></iframe>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: Not a dup. This is a text file with `.txt` extension.

Comment: try importing the file as an `object`

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how can you set a black background for the `IFRAME`, if there is txt file loaded? By default it is white.

Comment: The default background color for the IFrame with .txt files is the default body background color, so if you set your body blue, and put an IFrame containing a .txt file, it would be blue

Comment: Good question. Upvoting. And who was the joker who wants to close this as "not a real question"?

Answer (score 4):

This makes the trick at least in FF, IE and Opera.

```
document.getElementById('your_iframe_id').contentWindow.document.body.style.color='white';
```

In Chrome you can only change `IFRAME`s background color:

```
document.getElementById('your_iframe_id').style.background='white';
```

And for change background color in IE:

```
document.getElementById('your_iframe_id').contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
```

Then there is a big but... those expressions including `contentWindow`, work only, if the iframe and the host page are in the same domain.

(It is IE only having that white background by default)